# Stylesheet path incorrect after asp.net page postback in IE7, IE8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, stylesheet

I got a dropdownlist doing autopostback in aspx page.

The stylesheet loaded correctly when first load with path: *http://localhost/test/theme/style/mystyle.css*

When dropdownlist is selected and postback happened, the stylesheet loaded path become this: *http://localhost/theme/style/mystyle.css*

The loading sequence in IE7/IE8 load the wrong stylesheet path at first, and it load the correct path later. But my page using the stylesheet seems like style-less, every things are messed up.

Everything is working in Chrome, Safari, FireFox, IE9, it just went wrong in IE7, IE8.

Is there anyway to resolve this? It only happen to one page.

All stylesheets are included directly into aspx  section.

Comment: Can you please show how you link css files?

Comment: The link is generated by visual studio after i drag and drop it from the solution explorer, it works on other pages.

<link href="../../test/theme/style/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />

Answer (score 0):

If your vitual folder is `test` then please use the below in the master page to include the stylesheet

```
<link href="~/theme/style/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I've looked into the post and don't think that is my case, because I included all the css stylesheet link directly into aspx <head> section, and no @import was found in all related css

Comment: tried the method you recommended but doesn't work. It is an individual aspx page without master page by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the problem by adding the virtual folder directly into stylesheet link as below:

```
<link href="/test/theme/style/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Now it works on IE7, IE8.